# installing a 10,000W generator to a 240amp house

Tags: generator

I have a Firman H08053 10,000W generator. I would like to have it connected to my house which carried 240V.
When i do the calculations: 10,000 / 240v=41.6amps   if this is correct.

Should I use a 30amp or 50amp inlet box to connect to my house.
would it cause any tripping issues?
should the length of the cable from the generator to the house matter?

Comment: If the wire gauge is the proper size, then the length should not matter if in reasonable length of common extension cords ~50 feet or under.  Going above 100 feet, you might want to think about larger gauges.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see that model is actually 8000 W running and 10000 W starting. This means it can source 10000 W only for a brief time, likely a few seconds. The 8000 W running rating corresponds to 33.3 amps. The ratings are further reduced if it runs on propane.

The machine is equipped with an 14-50R receptacle. To utilize the full capacity of the generator through a single connection it would have to be this one. It would make sense to use a 50 amp inlet at the house as well.

There may be valid reasons why you would choose a 30 amp inlet instead. For example, availability of parts, or size and cost of 50 A building wiring and extension cord might cause a person to look at using the 30 A alternative. The choice is yours: if 30 A will be sufficient for your need, then provisioning for 50 A can be viewed as unnecessary extra cost.

Circuit breaker tripping issues will occur only if the demand in the house is greater than what you sized the connection to handle. Size carefully and then be attentive to use as planned. (See [Green Acres appliance system](https://www.google.com/search?q=green%20acres%20appliance%20system).)

The length of the cable from the house to the generator should not be a significant factor (within reason!) as long as it is appropriate gauge.